# Changing icon once label has been tapped

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-angular

So I'm working on this code:

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *">
    <Label text="Question" textWrap="true" (tap)="onTap(0)" class="h2 que" col="0"></Label>
    <Label class="fas h1 icon" text="&#xf107;" col="2" colSpan="3"></Label>
    <Label class="fas h1 icon" text="&#xf107;" col="2" colSpan="3"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

and its `.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer'
import { Application } from '@nativescript/core'
@Component({
    selector: 'faqs',
    templateUrl: './faqs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./faqs.component.css']
})

export class FaqsComponent implements OnInit {
    isToggled = [false, false, false, false]
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>Application.getRootView()
        sideDrawer.showDrawer()
    }

    onTap(index: number) {
        this.isToggled.fill(false, 0)
        this.isToggled[index] = !this.isToggled[index]
    }
}
```

I want the the `<Label class="fas h1 icon" text="&#xf108;" col="2" colSpan="3"></Label>` to show if the the `<Label text="Question" textWrap="true" (tap)="onTap(0)" class="h2 que" col="0"></Label>` has been tapped, just like an accordion. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `*ngIf` directive to conditionally display the Labels. The example below just uses the contents of your `isToggled` array to bind to the `*ngIf`, you can use any condition that's tied to your `onTap` event in a similar way.

```html
<GridLayout columns="*, *">
  <Label text="Question" textWrap="true" (tap)="onTap(0)" class="h2 que" col="0"></Label>
  <Label *ngIf="isToggled[0]" class="fas h1 icon" text="&#xf107;" col="2" colSpan="3"></Label>
  <Label *ngIf="isToggled[1]" class="fas h1 icon" text="&#xf108;" col="2" colSpan="3"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```